# meaning of 'core pool size' in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor's constructor

Tags: java, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I'm new to `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` (as I usually use the simple `Timer`, but people have been advising against it), and I don't quite understand what would be the appropriate integer value to pass to the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int)` constructor.

Could anyone explain this?

Thank you

Comment: For reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(int)

Answer (score 13):

In case of `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`, `corePoolSize` is maximum number of threads that will be created to perform scheduled actions.
This thread pool is fixed-sized and idle threads are kept alive.

DrunkenRabbit's answer is simply ivalid because `ScheduledThreadPoolsExecutor` docs says explicitly that (There will be no thread count spikes at all):

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the
>   inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, **because
>   it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads** and an
>   unbounded queue, **adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect.**

Now as for the value, reasonable number would be number of CPU cores that application is running on.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, the corePoolSize is the number of Threads to maintain in the pool.

eg. if you expect 10 concurrent requests on a regular basis, but peaks of 20. The corePoolSize should be 10 and max as 20. This way the executor will create up to 10 new threads, even if idle threads are available for use.

As stated in the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)

> Core and maximum pool sizes
>
> A ThreadPoolExecutor will automatically adjust the pool size (see getPoolSize()) according to the bounds set by corePoolSize (see getCorePoolSize()) and maximumPoolSize (see getMaximumPoolSize()). When a new task is submitted in method execute(java.lang.Runnable), and fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, a new thread is created to handle the request, even if other worker threads are idle. If there are more than corePoolSize but less than maximumPoolSize threads running, a new thread will be created only if the queue is full. By setting corePoolSize and maximumPoolSize the same, you create a fixed-size thread pool. By setting maximumPoolSize to an essentially unbounded value such as Integer.MAX_VALUE, you allow the pool to accommodate an arbitrary number of concurrent tasks. Most typically, core and maximum pool sizes are set only upon construction, but they may also be changed dynamically using setCorePoolSize(int) and setMaximumPoolSize(int).

Comment: Unfortunately ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor does not treat these parameters the same as ThreadPoolExecutor. STPE acts as a fixed thread pool of size 'corePoolSize' and does not create any additional threads. maximumPoolSize does nothing.

Comment: Echoing Mike Q statement on this. Seems like Java's implementation of the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor is buggy in this respect. Passing in only a core count won't set the max count in the getMaximumPoolSize API  and returns Integer.MAX_VALUE, which seems like a broken API if core and max are always intended to be the same. Why would they even implement the ThreadPoolExecutor interface if it wasn't intended to be used?

Comment: @Hazok, indeed `maxPoolSize` is not changed, but its value is disrespected by the implementation and actual `corePoolSize` will be used as max thread count.