# how to set maxPool size and keepAliveTime for ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class?

Tags: java

I want to set maxPool size and keepAliveTime manually.But,can set only while do following code

```
ExecutorService executorService = 
          new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,
          new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

ExecutorService class does not have "scheduleAtFixedRate(..)" method like this.So,i have to use only ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class which has scheduleAtFixedRate(..) method.if i use  ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor class ,i can't set manually like below(below code is not right.just for example)

```
ScheduledExecutorService schedule = 
          new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

(or)

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor schedule = 
          new ThreadPoolExecutor(10, 10, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS,new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Is there any way to set manually?? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>You can set it like this:</s>

```
final int corePoolSize = 10;
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize);
executor.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
executor.setKeepAliveTime(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

As Kenston Choi points out `setMaximumPoolSize` has no effect.

Here's the relevant section of the docs:

> While this class inherits from ThreadPoolExecutor, a few of the inherited tuning methods are not useful for it. In particular, because it acts as a fixed-sized pool using corePoolSize threads and an unbounded queue, adjustments to maximumPoolSize have no useful effect. Additionally, it is almost never a good idea to set corePoolSize to zero or use allowCoreThreadTimeOut because this may leave the pool without threads to handle tasks once they become eligible to run.

Since it only uses core pools this also means keep alive time is irrelevant.

I suppose your only option with this implementation is to tune `corePoolSize` and let any other tasks sit in the queue..

Comment: `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.setMaximumPoolSize` has no effect. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888366/meaning-of-core-pool-size-in-scheduledthreadpoolexecutors-constructor